# ArcGIS Python API - Item.Usage in Portal

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcgis

I've used the `arcgis.gis.Item.usage()` function before in ArcGIS Online, to ascertain how often/popular a specific service is, but the Python API webhelp says this is for ArcGIS Online only; see image below.

[image: ArcGIS Python API item usage]

https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html

Is there an alternative function to do this for items in Portal? Or any workarounds to get comparative usage data?